# How do I add Code(bound) to button to control a Function value in a WHERE Clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have this piece of code that controls the day(s) ago in a Date Add Function.

How do I embed this code to a form button, so that I can enter the days in a text box?

> WHERE
>   ((DateSerial(CInt(Left([MY_DATE],4)),CInt(Mid([MY_DATE],5,2)),CInt(Right([MY_DATE],2))))=DateAdd("d",-2,Date())))

I want to bound the day(s) to the button so I can type it in.

I already have the form and the button on it.

Comment: That looks overcomplicated to me. Where are you getting My_Date? Do you have a textbox as well as a button? You know you can just subtract and add days from dates in MS Office? If My_Date is a date, My_Date-2 is two days ago.

Comment: I have a table that contains a field named MY_DATE. I have already created the Textbox and the Label in Access. Example: Select * from thisTable where my_date is 1 day ago.

I am not following the reference to MS Office.

Comment: Dates are numbers in both Excel and Access and several other MS Office applications. The integer part is days and years and the decimal part is time. For example, cdate(41234)=21/11/2012, so you can just subtract and add integers for days.

Answer (score 0):

Where my_date is one day ago:

```
 Select * from thisTable where my_date=Date()-1
```

Choose:

```
 Select * from thisTable where my_date=Date()-[Enter date: ]
```

From a form:

```
 Select * from thisTable where my_date=Date()-Forms.MyForm.MyTextbox
```

It seems that the date is text format and it is not possible to change that, so:

```
SELECT CDate(Format([my_date],"0000-00-00")) AS DateFmt
FROM thisTable 
WHERE (((CDate(Format([my_date],"0000-00-00")))=Date()-Forms.MyForm.MyTextbox
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I'm not following, can you elaborate further? Please.

Comment: What's to follow? Paste example 2 into the query design window, sql view, and run it. Does it give you what you want?

Comment: Okay I finally assemble this code, using the above example as a reference but I am getting the following error message:

**The Microsoft Database Engine does not Recognized 

Forms.myform!thetextbox as a valid field name or expression.**

This is what the code looks like in my SQL:

`WHERE ((DateSerial(CInt(Left([MY_DATE],4)), CInt(Mid([MY_DATE],5,2)), CInt(Right([MY_DATE],2)))) = DateAdd("d",-Forms.myform!thetextbox,Date())))`

Comment: Where is this in VBA or in a query?

Comment: It is directly placed in the SQL Query, no VBA involved.

Comment: Why has dateadd reappeared? You do not need it. Have you tried a query set up as I show in example 3. No dateadd.

Comment: I did try that and this is what it looks like in the SQL:

`((DateSerial(CInt(Left([MY_DATE],4)),CInt(Mid([MY_DATE],5,2)),CInt(Right([MY_DATE],2))))=Date()-[Forms].[myform]![thetxtbox]))`

Still getting the same error message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6931/discussion-between-remou-and-unaverage-guy)